# How can I split my dataframe into two rows where two columns have specific values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which contains information by column such as:

```
Month  Year     Cost_1 Cost_2
1      2017     100    0
2      2017     0      100
3      2017     140    30
```

and I am looking to transpose this data so that it takes the form:

```
Month  Year     Cost_1 Cost_2 Type
1      2017     100    0      Cost_1
2      2017     0      100    Cost_2
3      2017     140    0      Cost_1
3      2017     0      30     Cost_2
```

My initial thought was to use .loc(Cost_1>0,"Type")="Cost_1" but this wouldn't deal with the rows which have both Cost_1 and Cost_2 and need a new row adding? Should I split the data so that it has only Cost_1 or Cost_2 first and then use .loc to create the Type column or is there a smarter way to do this?

Edit:

The problem is actually more complicated than I first thought. Each column has an associated partner Cost_1 has Count_1, Cost_2 has Count_2.. etc.

```
   Year  Month BDADExclIncurred_Capped_count  BDADExclIncurred_Capped_mean  BDTPDIncurred_Capped_count BDTPDIncurred_Capped_mean
0  2015      5                             0                         NaN                          60                         900
1  2015     10                             0                         NaN                           0                         NaN 
2  2015     12                             0                         NaN                           0                         NaN 
3  2016      1                            60                        2000                           0                         NaN 
4  2016      1                           100                        1500                          20                         600
```

This is how my data looks before, with many columns broken up into count:mean pairs, I want to keep those together but if there is a row with two count:mean pairs I want that to be split into two rows, where each has only one corresponding count:mean pair. Then I wish to create a new column called "type" which tells me what the count:mean pair associated with that row is.

```
   Year  Month BDADExclIncurred_Capped_count  BDADExclIncurred_Capped_mean  BDTPDIncurred_Capped_count BDTPDIncurred_Capped_mean Type
0  2015      5                             0                         NaN                          60                         900  TPD
1  2015     10                             0                         NaN                           0                         NaN  
2  2015     12                             0                         NaN                           0                         NaN  
3  2016      1                            60                        2000                           0                         NaN  AD
4  2016      1                           100                        1500                           0                           0  AD
5  2016      1                             0                           0                          20                         600  TPD
```

As show in this example, a new row is created. Index 4 from the previous dataframe is now split into both index 4 and index 5.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming either only `Cost_1` or `Cost_2` are greater than zero, as your example suggests, here's an simple approach to populate `Type` with `Cost_1` and `Cost_2` in one step:

```
c = ['Cost_1','Cost_2']
counts = df[c].gt(0).dot(df[c].columns + ',').str.rstrip(',').str.split(',')
counts_df = pd.DataFrame(counts.tolist(), columns = ['Count_1', 'Count_2'])
df.assign(**counts_df)

    Month  Year  Cost_1 Count_1  Cost_2 Count_2
0      1  2017     100  Cost_1       0       0
1      2  2017       0  Cost_2     100       0
2      3  2017     140  Cost_1      30  Cost_2
```

Comment: Will this not just create the new column "Type" without addressing the row splitting?

Comment: But I'm not sure what you mean with row splitting. Can you give an example with such problem, and the expected output you'd like? @Violatic

Comment: I have tried to expand my question to better explain the problem. When I used your method it created a column Type but it contained the entire list of columns without spacing rather than just one or the other.

Comment: @Violatic - chweck eited answer.

Comment: Yess, thx @jezrael. Was heading there. But I think it might be a little tricky when assigning these lists to the 2 new columns. Will give it a look now

Comment: Well the solution got a little uglier than before, but  it does the job i guess :) @jezrael

Comment: Yeah I know...I guess I could add another option reconstructing from  Dataframe.tolist()

Comment: Okay fixed. Should be okay now @Violatic

Comment: Are you sure solution is OK? Because OP need duplicated rows.

Comment: Not sure what OP is expecting. I'll wait see what he thinks of current soln

Comment: This seems to not be keeping the count but instead replacing the count with whether or not it is cost_1 or cost_2. I think I am explaining what I want poorly. I have again tried to update the top diagram to better explain. But I will try to think of a better explanation in the meantime

Comment: The most improtatn @Violatic here is to give a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Will give it a look later

Comment: I think that the example I have given should explain what I am looking for. With a final type column and paired other columns.

Comment: @yatu I believe I have improved my edit to explain the problem in a more complete manner now.